# Use the $.ajax().responseText to write in a var in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, variables

even if there are lots of questions related to my issue, I was not able to find a proper answer.

In an external JS I need a value of a session variable (view_mode). It has two possible values ("complex" & "simple"). I want to check which value is set und do further stuff depending on the result.

Using following code, JS alerts the correct value (lets say "complex") but with some spaces (like "    complex"). When it comes to the if(...) it cannot use the 'view' variable even if I write 'if(view == "    complex")'. Just like the variable 'view' doesn't exist or has some other value it jumps always into the 'else'.

```
var view = $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    async: false, 
                    url: 'get_view_mode.php',
                }).responseText;
alert(view);

if(view == "complex"){
  //do something
}else{
  //do something else
}
```

Obviously the "complex" is written in the variable otherwise it wouldn't be able to alert the correct text. But why is it not possible to use it further in any other way? 
(Yes, I know that ajax is thought to be used for async use ;) )

I appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: Depending on the datatype a man probably has to eval or parse the value before using it properly.

Comment: Because `" complex "` and similar do not equal `"complex"`. The former has spaces, the latter does not. Remove the whitespace before doing the comparison, perhaps with `.trim()` (depending on what browser support you need). Or use `indexOf`. Beware of capitalization.

Comment: @Lain  regarding your comment about the JQuery a link I provided: the passage you are referencing does not refer to the overall object returned by the Ajax call. What it is referring to is the XHR wrapper object that is passed into the call back functions. The $.ajax call returns a JQuery Deferred as the docs. indicate.

Comment: @Scott Marcus: https://s15.postimg.org/fixfy1vu3/Whatever.png

Comment: @ T.J. Crowder, I checked already whether the issue is just the spaces... But it is not. trimming or just adding spaces to fit the if does not work.

Comment: @Lain Yes, I stand corrected. Although, the returned object does actually implement the Deferred interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check your PHP file to make sure it's not outputting anything you don't expect (eg. spaces)

But in this case you can get away with `if( view.match(/complex/))`.

In general, however, I would suggest something like this in your `<head>`:

```
<script>
    window.SESSION = <?php
        echo json_encode(array(
            "view_mode" => $_SESSION['view_mode'],
            // add more values here?
        ));
    ?>
</script>
```

This way, you can access the value directly in JS with `window.SESSION.view_mode` without having to do an extra round-trip to the server.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be the perfect solution for me, so far. Is it also possible to do it the other way round? Change the variable in the script?